# Flask_login - LOGIN_DISABLED = True, doesnt seem to work after LoginManager initiation

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I want the `@login_required` to be disabled when the python file is run standalone(dev mode), but it seems that it cant be disabled after `flask_login.LoginManager()` initiation.
When i run this code on a http server, i want Flask_login to be enabled.

I found a couple of ways to do this, but that doesnt seem to work. Here is one:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.config.update(dict(LOGIN_DISABLED=True))
        print(app.config)
```

The printout gives me a string that ends with: `...'LOGIN_DISABLED': True}>`. Which means that the setting is saved. But still, its not disabled.

I was checking the doc's of Flask_login and found:

> [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/409

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An update has fixed this: https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/pull/410/files

For older versions before the above patch, you can disable login by setting the attribute on LoginManager directly instead of updating the flask config:

`login_manager._login_disabled = True`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by youself

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['LOGIN_DISABLED'] = True


@basic_auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    if app.config['LOGIN_DISABLED']:
        return True
```